# PHP/Mysql Compare uploaded files to ensure no redundant data

Tags: php, mysql

So i'm storing uploaded files in a mysql database.
To make sure that there are no duplicate files in the database I create a md5 hash of very file and store it as well.

On file upload I get the hash of the new file and check if it already exists in the database.

**DB Table**

id, file_name, file_binary, file_hash

Now since i discovered that there is the possibility of hash collisions i want to compare the files byte by byte.

What's the best and fastest approach to do that with PHP/Mysql or what would be the best way to ensure files are not uploaded twice (to conserve storage).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unless you have billions of files, it's so extremely unlikely that any two will collide unless a person is trying to make it happen. Another option is to store two hashes for a file, one MD5 and one SHA1, for example, and make sure both are unique. Generally speaking, the chances of a collision in MD5 are 1/(2^128) = 1/340282366920938463463374607431768211456

Comment: As Colin pointed out the chances of two files having the same hash is tiny. How tiny? Well think of ten people that you know. The chance of a hash collision is about the same as these ten people getting struck by lightning in the same year. TINY! If you want to be double sure do a MD5 and SHA-1 as mentioned above.

Comment: thanks colin & namphibian for pointing the low possibility out. I also like the idea of another hash generated by a different algorithm. Feel free to post it as an answer and i'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to reduce the already minor risk of a collision would be to create another hash with a different algorithm like SHA1.

**DB Table**

> id, file_name, file_binary, file_hash_md5, file_hash_sha1

A check query could look like this then:

```
SELECT id FROM files_table WHERE file_hash_md5 = '78b7d929110959d1de58a32e9d331512' AND file_hash_sha1 = 'cc73882a1395af392b6cb005c45d19869bfa485a'
```